# Question about whether to include something in the __init__() method

Tags: python, oop

I am new to OOP and hence, am looking for suggestions on good practice for coding something where the following issue arises.

I am defining a `Seller(a, b, c, d)` class. There are many attributes of this class, two of which are, `mostRecentProfit` and `profitHistory`. However, values of these two are not known when the class is initialized. Some other steps in the program have to be executed before these are realized. My questions is:

In the `__init__(a, b, c, d)` of the seller class, should I write

```
self.mostRecentProfit = None
self.profitHistory = []
```

or, should I not define these at all in the `__init__` method. The reason former appears attractive to me is that by looking at the `__init__()` method, I can know all the attributes for the class. However, that may not be a good reason for doing this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please also consider following the standard Python naming guidelines set forth in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - self.most_recent_profit and self.profit_history.

Comment: @Chris...that's as bad as prescribing indentation...oh, wait. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define them. In my experience, not doing so when the code dealing with the instances makes frequent references to those properties, means you end up forever typing `if object.profitHistory:` before looping etc. With an empty list there, you can skip those conditions. And as you say, it makes it much more legible.

Comment: +1 Define them if they're necessary for the class to function, don't if they're not.

Answer (score 4):

Defining the attributes in `__init__()` makes the code better for when someone who has not seen the code has to start working with it. It can be confusing when a class starts accessing an attribute that doesn't seem to exist at first.

Also, since one of your default values is a list instead of `None`, initializing it means you can always treat the attribute as a list and never have to worry about it's state.

Comment: The OP's question was **if** he should be defining them. If he is not defining the attributes, then he is not initializing it to anything. My comment about the list was to give further support of why defining them made sense (as it would need to be initialized when first used).

Answer (score 1):

I would define them all in the `__init()` method because that would not only document what they all normally were, but if you define their default values to all be something valid, allow most of the rest of your code to easily process instances of the class even if these attributes never get updated.

So, in your example, that would mean initializing `self.mostRecentProfit` to `0` or perhaps `0.0` rather than `None`. Doing this would allow it to be used as a number without checking for it's existence with a value not equal to `None` before each reference to it or wrapping each of them in a `try/except` block to handle the cases where they were never explicitly set to another value.